# Adding multiple Lines of text into UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Hi I want to display some text in my UILabel line by line when an action is occurred

Hi, I have a textbox, button and a UILabel, lets say I've typed in 
"This text will be displayed line by line in a UILabel"
and pressed the button to display the text in the UILabel..

so inside the UILabel it will look like:

```
This
text
will
be
displayed
line
by
line
in
a
UILabel
```

....

I've been searching forums but could not found an answer.. so I don't know if this is possible..  please help
p.s I've set number of lines to 0 and line breaks is set to word wrap

Comment: Can you be more explicit with what you've actually tried and the actual results you're getting?  Where did you set number of lines?  Where did you set line break style?  Where did you set the text?  What does your actual result look like?

Comment: this solution covers your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679370/swift-uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text

Answer (score 4):

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 300)) // make the height biggest
```

//    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

//    label.numberOfLines = 0
dont work if label width bigger word width

```
var string = "This text will be displayed line by line in a UILabel"

var array = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var newstring = join("\r", array)
label.text = newstring
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let labelText = "Write\rthe\rtext\rwith\rline\rbreaks."
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have to be a UILabel?

You could use UITextField instead which has some advantageous handling options

Answer (score 0):

In order to wrap your text within a UILabel on Xcode 6 and above

1. Select the label you are working with.
2. Navigate to the Utilities panel.
3. Select the "Attributes inspector"
4. Select the number of lines you would like to display on the label (2,3,4) depending on the size of your UILabel field
5. Select "Word Wrap" under Line Breaks, or you can select any option of your preference.
   You may manipulate the way your text appears to your taste.

[image: screen grab of Xcode fields]